# What does the new NDK plugins do?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk

I was installing the last ADT version on eclipse and there's some NDK plugins (https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/). Does anybody know what is does? Does it allow eclipse do compile native code? How do you use it?
I can't find any documentation out there.

Answer (score 4):

NDK is a toolset that allows you to write part of your android app using native code in languages such as C and C++.  Many developers will probably not need this for android development, however, for accessing certain libraries and optimizing performance it can be useful.
[Check out a description here:](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

[This page](http://tools.android.com/recent/usingthendkplugin) explains how to build Native Applications using the NDK plugins